# Contact Form 7 - how manipulate data before mail is sent?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am creating a bilingual site. I have a form with various fields and one of them is a datepicker (using the template's tools - the datepicker passes thedata in a text field). When the user chooses "English" for a strange reason the date changes format and from dd-mm-yy becomes mm-dd-yy. I was not able to find a solution with the template's tools so I thought that before the form is sent to the owner of the site there would be a mechanism that checks if the language is english and if yes then it parses the field, makes the adjustement and then sends the form. So far I was able to access this data but I am not able to modify it.

I have created a hook (before_send_mail) and in there

$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
$data = $submission->get_posted_data();

$data['date'] gives me the access to the field, I can modify it, even save a file with the value but the email that arrives contains the values unaltered.
What can I do to alter the value of the field before it is sent?

*Please do not tell me to change the field from text to date or to contact the template's creator. The first one is not possible the second is ongoing.*

Comment: If it is ongoing, then please stick with that route and see how it turns out. Not posting anything from this conversation and probably vice versa is equal to a slap in ones face: You are doubling the efforts on both ends. Please, do **not** do that. Anywhere. At any time.

Comment: Well.....hmmmmm.....searching alternative routes is a slap on the face of someone? The route chosen with contacting the author has other types of solutions. I have chosen the one I mentioned in this site because it will provide me a better way in handling Wordpress and the way it comunicates with the various plugins - regardless of the template - knowledge I could use in the future and help others. I thought that this was the point of this site. I guess not. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: By "route", I meant "support route". If you are in contact with the author, stick with that. Again: You are doubling the efforts on his as well as on our end. No one appreciates that, so yes, that bothers people.

Answer (score 1):

This could be outdated but I suggest [turning on your `debug_log`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) and print the following code in the `before_send_mail` hook:

```
error_log( print_r( $submission, 1 ) );
```

That will give you an idea of what you're dealing with. The below may be outdated but I think what you need to modify is the `$submission->mail` array.